# how to grant aws config write permission to a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I modify the SourceAccountID to be my organzation ID since AWS Config does not support organization ID or organization unit based condition?I have alot of accounts and I do not want to write them all out individually.

```
{
  "Sid":"AWSConfigBucketDelivery",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  ""Principal": {
      "Service":[
       "config.amazonaws.com"
      ]
},
"Action": "s3:PutObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::targetBucketName/[optional] prefix/AWSLogs/sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens/Config/*",
"Condition": { 
  "StringEquals": { 
     "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
}
```

Comment: Sadly its not clear what you want to do. Can you provide more details about your setup, TF code? The policy that you are trying to do, what is it? You run your tf under master account? There is lots of details missing from your question.

Comment: I want AWS Config from other accounts to be able to write in my bucket in the management account without having to name them individually like where it says sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens in my code